# Book about 2-4 kids who go to a mansion and a statue comes alive to chase them

Tags: story-identification, books

The house transports them to somewhere I cant fully remember. In a later book I believe they go to an old Roman arena and the older child fights in it.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. I am sure you can come up with some extra details here. When did you read this? Can you remember anything more about the kids? Did they live in this house, or was the house just a plot-device for a single book? How old were the kids?

Comment: 2017 or 2018. The house was a relatives an aunts or grandparents, the kids were around 13 and a baby  i believe

Comment: 2 13 year olds.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: so a scene that i distinctly remember was  after going into the garden than the statue come alive and tries to attack the kids they run back to the house hide in a room and the house statrts flying over a desert